# tryCatch within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, try-catch, warnings

I am new to R and I have checked most links online but I have not been able to solve the problem. 
 Here is a reproducible example of a Monte Carlo simulation I am doing:

```
rm(list = ls())
x=c(-2,3,-1,4,'A')
y=rep(0,5)

for(i in 1:5){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      y[i]=log(x[i])
    },
    error = function(e){
      message('Caught an error!',i)
      return(NA)
    },
    warning = function(w){
      message('Caught an warning!',i)
      return(NA)
    }
  ) 

}
```

Please how do I fix the code so that at the end of the for loop, R returns the values of y as

```
y= NA,log(3),NA,log(4),NA
i=1,3,5
```

and the values of i where there was an error or warning. 
That is, error and warnings are replaced with NA and successful evaluations are returned and the values of i where there was an error or warning are also returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise `y` with `NA` and then run the `for` loop. Also since `x` is a vector and vector can hold only one class all the numbers in `x` turn to characters as you have non-numeric elements in `x` so you need to convert them to numbers before taking `log`.

```
x=c(-2,3,-1,4,'A')
y=rep(NA,5)

for(i in 1:5){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      y[i]= log(as.numeric(x[i]))
    },
  error = function(e){
      message('Caught an error!',i)
   },
  warning = function(w){
      message('Caught a warning! ',i)
    }
  ) 
}
#Caught a warning! 1
#Caught a warning! 3
#Caught a warning! 5

y
#[1]       NA 1.098612       NA 1.386294       NA
```

and then use `is.na` with `which` to get the index where error or warning happened.

```
which(is.na(y))
#[1] 1 3 5
```

---

Of course, you can do this without `for` loop as well

```
y <- log(as.numeric(x))
which(is.na(y))
#[1] 1 3 5
```

---

To `return` different value based on error or warning, we can make this into a function

```
run_fun <- function(x) {
   tryCatch(
     expr = {
      return(log(as.numeric(x)))
     },
     error = function(e){
       message('Caught an error!',i)
       return(100)
      },
      warning = function(w){
        message('Caught a warning! ',i)
        return(200)
       }
      ) 
 }
```

and then call it in `for` loop.

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
   y[i] <- run_fun(x[i])
}

y
#[1] 200.0000   1.0986 200.0000   1.3863 200.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two questions please: 1.  is there a specified way to return a particular choice of a number if there is an error or warning? Say, return 100 for error and 200 for a warning?  2. Why as.numeric() because I want to replace a bunch of optimization codes under the expr part of tryCatch?

Comment: @dms 1) yes, you can change it into a function and return whatever value you want. See last part of my updated answer. 2) If you check `class(x)` you'll see that it is of class character, you cannot take `log` of character value hence you need to convert it into numeric with `as.numeric`.