# Creating multiple GLM in a for loop, skipping models in the loop where the coefficients do not work in R

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression, glm

I have created a list that contains all possible combinations of my dependent variables and I am trying to create multiple glm with all of those combinations.

```
combinations = list()
models = list()
for(i in length(combinations) {                 
 models[[i]]<- glm ( as.formula(paste("(x) ~", combinations[i])),  family= 'Gamma' , data = df)
}
```

I get the error message:

**Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values**

I know that is because one or a few models the combination of dependent variables seems to create some issues. How can I skip the models that create those issues (or leave them blank) and keep the loop going?

As a side comment: I tried implementing a normal exponential glm, which worked, but I would really like to stay with the gamma family.

```
combinations = list()
models = list()
for(i in length(combinations) {                 
 models[[i]]<- glm ( as.formula(paste("exp(x) ~", combinations[i])),  family= 'gaussian' , data = df)
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can help you more. Here is a guide for sharing the `dput` of your data: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: See `?tryCatch`

Comment: Many thanks @MikkoMarttila! With the help of tryCatch and with the inspiration of this other [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084750/trycatch-within-for-loop) I was able to resolve my issues :)